# Multiple AJAX in one window.onload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm sure this question must have been asked before but I'm really struggling
to find the answer anywhere so have finally given up and will consult
the stackoverflow community - hopefully there's someone out there who's seen
it all before and can help me out!

I have a webpage which needs to make some function calls as the page loads. It is an ajax method which calls the Json method from the controller which supplies the data that will be used to draw the chart.

I've successfully displayed one chart on my page but still need to display two more charts. Is it possible to have multiple ajax methods on window.onload function?

Here is my code so far.

```
    window.onload = function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/CRM/GetIndustryTypeData",
            data: JSON,
            success: function (data) {
                IndTypePieChart(data);
            },
            error: function () { alert("Error"); }
        });



}
```

Comment: Of course (you can get rid of the `window.onload = function () {` and just have multiple `$.ajax()` calls - positioned at the bottom of the page or wrapped in `$(document).ready()`). but why are you not using a view model and passing the data to the view when the page is first generated?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will try that Sir. I have a method in my Controller to get the data that I need (retrieved through a stored procedure) . Here is the code: http://pastie.org/10916246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)'s answer will work 100%. Get rid of `window.onload = function(){` and have any number of `$.ajax()` calls - positioned at the bottom of the page or wrapped in `$(document).ready(){
})`.

Comment: @KylieIrwin, Then perhaps you should consider accepting the answer.